# Question about relativistic KE

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, particle-physics

I'm a bit stumped by this question:

As an electron approaches the speed of light, continuously adding KE to it will result in which of the following?

A: allows it to travel faster than the speed of light

B: reduces its mass

C: makes it travel close but not faster than the speed of light

D: distorts time and creates a time dilation

The answer is C, but I wouldve thought it would be C and D. How does it not cause time dilation? Im confused